# How is an element in set(list) but not list?

Tags: python, pandas, series

How can an element be a member of a collection, but not a member of the unique elements of the collection? Am I  thinking of `set` wrong?

```
>>> propertyID
4
>>> propertyID in output['propertyID']
True
>>> propertyID in set(output['propertyID'])
False

>>> output['propertyID']
0     42
1     42
2     42
3     42
4     42
5     42
6     42
7     42
0     41
0     40
1     40
2     40
3     40
4     40
5     40
6     40
7     40
8     40
9     40
10    40

>>> type(output['propertyID'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Is `output['propertyID']` a list?

Comment: Could you, please post what `output` is? Especially, `type(output['propertyID'])`

Comment: Asking this question without showing the list is difficult to know what do you mean

Comment: There are two reasons why that can be the case: (a) hashing does not satisfies contracts, and (b) equality checks do not follow contracts. Furthermore the `output['propertyID']` object could have implemented a `__contains__` and `__iter__` that differ.

Comment: You could have printed `set(output['propertyID'])` and found out....

Comment: I think the questioner made two mistakes:
1: like Attersson said, if you tried `print(set(...))` you would have gotten the answer and learned something about Pandas Series.
2: the question title does not match the actual question, the actual problem is `x in set(Series)` vs. `x in Series` but the question said `set(list)` vs `list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Membership tests with Pandas work the same way as dictionaries. In the case of `pd.Series`, the keys are indices and values are series values.

For example, `1 in {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}` will return `True`. Similarly, `4 in output['propertyID']` checks for membership in the index. `set` triggers extraction of values and conversion to a `set` object. You can see the index of your series via `output['propertyID'].index`.

There are other ways you can extract values: `pd.Series.values` via its NumPy array representation and `pd.Series.tolist` via conversion to Python list.

Note the converse is also true. You will find `42 in set(output['propertyID'])` returns `True`, whereas `42 in output['propertyID']` returns `False` if there is no such index in the series.